# Add content to groupeditemspage in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, httpclient

When I create GroupedItemsPage, it have DataModel/SampleDataSource.cs for example

but how I can add content that I load from Internet and modify with Fizzler ?

```
 public sealed class SampleDataSource
  {
    string a = "";
    private static SampleDataSource _sampleDataSource = new SampleDataSource();

    private ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup> _allGroups = new ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup>();
    public ObservableCollection<SampleDataGroup> AllGroups
    {
        get { return this._allGroups; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SampleDataGroup> GetGroups(string uniqueId)
    {
        if (!uniqueId.Equals("AllGroups")) throw new ArgumentException("Only 'AllGroups' is supported as a collection of groups");

        return _sampleDataSource.AllGroups;
    }

    public static SampleDataGroup GetGroup(string uniqueId)
    {
        // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
        var matches = _sampleDataSource.AllGroups.Where((group) => group.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
        if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
        return null;
    }

    public static SampleDataItem GetItem(string uniqueId)
    {
        // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
        var matches = _sampleDataSource.AllGroups.SelectMany(group => group.Items).Where((item) => item.UniqueId.Equals(uniqueId));
        if (matches.Count() == 1) return matches.First();
        return null;
    }

    public async Task<string> DownloadStringContent()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
        var result = await response.RequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return result;
    }

    public async void setA()
    {
        a = await DownloadStringContent();
        while (a == "") ;
    }

    public SampleDataSource()
    {
        setA();
        String ITEM_CONTENT = a;
        //String ITEM_CONTENT = String.Format("Item Content: {0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}\n\n{0}",
          //          "Curabitur class aliquam vestibulum nam curae maecenas sed integer cras phasellus suspendisse quisque donec dis praesent accumsan bibendum pellentesque condimentum adipiscing etiam consequat vivamus dictumst aliquam duis convallis scelerisque est parturient ullamcorper aliquet fusce suspendisse nunc hac eleifend amet blandit facilisi condimentum commodo scelerisque faucibus aenean ullamcorper ante mauris dignissim consectetuer nullam lorem vestibulum habitant conubia elementum pellentesque morbi facilisis arcu sollicitudin diam cubilia aptent vestibulum auctor eget dapibus pellentesque inceptos leo egestas interdum nulla consectetuer suspendisse adipiscing pellentesque proin lobortis sollicitudin augue elit mus congue fermentum parturient fringilla euismod feugiat");

        var group1 = new SampleDataGroup("Group-1",
                "Group Title: 1",
                "Group Subtitle: 1",
                "Assets/DarkGray.png",
                "Group Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempor scelerisque lorem in vehicula. Aliquam tincidunt, lacus ut sagittis tristique, turpis massa volutpat augue, eu rutrum ligula ante a ante");
        group1.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-1-Item-1",
                "Item Title: 1",
                "Item Subtitle: 1",
                "Assets/LightGray.png",
                "Item Description: Pellentesque porta, mauris quis interdum vehicula, urna sapien ultrices velit, nec venenatis dui odio in augue. Cras posuere, enim a cursus convallis, neque turpis malesuada erat, ut adipiscing neque tortor ac erat.",
                ITEM_CONTENT,
                group1));
        group1.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-1-Item-2",
                "Item Title: 2",
                "Item Subtitle: 2",
                "Assets/DarkGray.png",
                "Item Description: Pellentesque porta, mauris quis interdum vehicula, urna sapien ultrices velit, nec venenatis dui odio in augue. Cras posuere, enim a cursus convallis, neque turpis malesuada erat, ut adipiscing neque tortor ac erat.",
                ITEM_CONTENT,
                group1));
        group1.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-1-Item-3",
                "Item Title: 3",
                "Item Subtitle: 3",
                "Assets/MediumGray.png",
                "Item Description: Pellentesque porta, mauris quis interdum vehicula, urna sapien ultrices velit, nec venenatis dui odio in augue. Cras posuere, enim a cursus convallis, neque turpis malesuada erat, ut adipiscing neque tortor ac erat.",
                ITEM_CONTENT,
                group1));
        group1.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-1-Item-4",
                "Item Title: 4",
                "Item Subtitle: 4",
                "Assets/DarkGray.png",
                "Item Description: Pellentesque porta, mauris quis interdum vehicula, urna sapien ultrices velit, nec venenatis dui odio in augue. Cras posuere, enim a cursus convallis, neque turpis malesuada erat, ut adipiscing neque tortor ac erat.",
                ITEM_CONTENT,
                group1));
        group1.Items.Add(new SampleDataItem("Group-1-Item-5",
                "Item Title: 5",
                "Item Subtitle: 5",
                "Assets/MediumGray.png",
                "Item Description: Pellentesque porta, mauris quis interdum vehicula, urna sapien ultrices velit, nec venenatis dui odio in augue. Cras posuere, enim a cursus convallis, neque turpis malesuada erat, ut adipiscing neque tortor ac erat.",
                ITEM_CONTENT,
                group1));
        this.AllGroups.Add(group1);
    }
}
```

I want to modify string in SampleDataSource by download string from httpclient but there are nothing in a

how I handle this? help me please

Comment: what have you tried? You will have to create an async method that does this for you (since all HTTP calls are async). Unfortunately, the sample app populates the data model in a constructor, and you can't make the constructor async and just include the HttpClient calls there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe read in MSDN documents core levels..

Web services return 2 model method :

- Normal Method
- Async method

if you want use async method, declare in method identify "async" clause.
if call a web service method async and if add "await" clause: method waiting to web method response. in this time, don't reach under code line.

and constuctors don't support async clause.

bind your collection a control. still downloading to show in control. Derive your class INotifyProperty.

regards.